# Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2036) at

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

error was created in the total activity java class

here is the logcat

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.TotalActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
>       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
>       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
>       at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2036)
>       at com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.TotalActivity.onCreate(TotalActivity.java:33)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7117)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7108)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027) 
>       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101) 
>       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

here is the place error occured

```
enter c while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), st.nextElement().toString().substring(0,1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    test = st.nextElement().toString().substring(3,1);
    if(count>0)
        total+= Float.parseFloat(test);
    count++;
}
```

here is the total activity java class file

```
 mApp=((pizza) getApplicationContext());
et_summary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_summary);
tv_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have chosen the" + " " +  mApp.getGlobalVarValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
et_summary.setText(mApp.getGlobalVarValue());
String str = mApp.getGlobalVarValue();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"$");
String test="";
float total=0;
int count=0;
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), st.nextElement().toString().substring(0,1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    test = st.nextElement().toString().substring(3,1);
    if(count>0)
        total+= Float.parseFloat(test);
    count++;
}
et_summary.setText(mApp.getGlobalVarValue());
tv_total.setText("Total :" + total+"");
mApp.setGlobalClear();


}
public boolean isFloat( String input )
{
try
{
    Float.parseFloat( input );
    return true;
}
catch( Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't substring from 3 to 1
Swap

```
substring(3,1);
```

for

```
substring(1,3)
```

Comment: it didnt work, now showing different error.    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3

Comment: it didnt work. now showing different error.  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3

Comment: wait you know indexes start at 0 right? try `substring(0,2)`

Comment: then It'd be much appreciated if you could press the little tick left of my answer to accept it :)